# Instantiation of class in BPEL process

Tags: bpel

I have a very Strange problem, in my BPEL process I have used java embed Activity. on that activity if I am using Task class. then I am not able to deploy my process. its giving me following message.

when I remove that line then I am able to deploy that process.

following error comes when deployment.

> [10:29:41 AM] ----  Deployment
>   started.  ---- [10:29:41 AM] Target
>   platform is  (Weblogic 10.3).
>   [10:29:41 AM] Running dependency
>   analysis... [10:29:41 AM] Building...
>   [10:29:52 AM] Deploying profile...
>   [10:30:19 AM] Wrote Archive Module to
>   D:\RegistrationUpload\RegistrationUpload\RegistrationUpload\deploy\sca_RegistrationUpload_rev21.0.jar
>   [10:30:19 AM] Deploying
>   sca_RegistrationUpload_rev21.0.jar to
>   partition "default" on server
>   soa_server1
>   [WIN-73I7I7QL8Z3.uradevt.gov.sg:8002] 
>   [10:30:19 AM] Processing
>   sar=/D:/RegistrationUpload/RegistrationUpload/RegistrationUpload/deploy/sca_RegistrationUpload_rev21.0.jar
>   [10:30:19 AM] Adding sar file -
>   D:\RegistrationUpload\RegistrationUpload\RegistrationUpload\deploy\sca_RegistrationUpload_rev21.0.jar
>   [10:30:19 AM] Preparing to send HTTP
>   request for deployment [10:30:19 AM]
>   Creating HTTPS connection to
>   host:WIN-73I7I7QL8Z3.uradevt.gov.sg,
>   port:8002 [10:30:19 AM] Sending
>   internal deployment descriptor
>   [10:30:20 AM] Sending archive -
>   sca_RegistrationUpload_rev21.0.jar
>   [10:33:45 AM] Received HTTP response
>   from the server, response code=500
>   [10:33:45 AM] Error deploying archive
>   sca_RegistrationUpload_rev21.0.jar to
>   partition "default" on server
>   soa_server1
>   [WIN-73I7I7QL8Z3.uradevt.gov.sg:8002] 
>   [10:33:45 AM] HTTP error code returned
>   [500] [10:33:45 AM] Error message from
>   server: Error during deployment: Error
>   occurred during deployment of
>   component: OfficerList to service
>   engine: implementation.bpel, for
>   composite: RegistrationUpload:
>   ORABPEL-01005
>
> Failed to compile bpel generated
>   classes. failure to compile the
>   generated BPEL classes for BPEL
>   process "OfficerList" of composite
>   "default/RegistrationUpload!21.0*soa_27af417b-20d6-48d0-821c-4f26b3c4ce94" The class path setting is incorrect.
>   Ensure that the class path is set
>   correctly. If this happens on the
>   server side, verify that the custom
>   classes or jars which this BPEL
>   process is depending on are deployed
>   correctly. Also verify that the run
>   time is using the same
>   release/version.  .  [10:33:45 AM]
>   Check server log for more details.
>   [10:33:45 AM] Error deploying archive
>   sca_RegistrationUpload_rev21.0.jar to
>   partition "default" on server
>   soa_server1
>   [WIN-73I7I7QL8Z3.uradevt.gov.sg:8002] 
>   [10:33:45 AM] ####  Deployment
>   incomplete.  #### [10:33:45 AM] Error
>   deploying archive
>   file:/D:/RegistrationUpload/RegistrationUpload/RegistrationUpload/deploy/sca_RegistrationUpload_rev21.0.jar
>   (oracle.tip.tools.ide.fabric.deploy.common.SOARemoteDeployer)

follwing code I have used in snippet.

```
<bpelx:exec import="org.w3c.dom.Element"/>
    <bpelx:exec import="com.ura.dams.workflow.process.OfficerList"/>
    <bpelx:exec import="oracle.bpel.services.workflow.task.model.Task"/>
    <bpelx:exec name="getTaskInfoForPO" version="1.5" language="java">
      <![CDATA[try                        
{                
      OfficerList officerlist= new OfficerList();               
      String JobAssignmentType1= (String)getVariableData("JobAssignmentType");                 
      String officerLevel1= (String)getVariableData("officerLevel");                 
      String applicationType1= (String)getVariableData("applicationType");                 
      String functionId1= (String)getVariableData("functionId");                 
      String dcConservationFlag1= (String)getVariableData("dcConservationFlag");                 
      String app_id_key1= (String)getVariableData("app_id_key");                 
      String app_id_value1= (String)getVariableData("app_id_value");                 
      String taskID1= (String)getVariableData("taskID");       
      String officer="";       
      String DConservatiionFlag="";       

      java.util.Hashtable keyValues= new java.util.Hashtable();            
        keyValues.put(app_id_key1, app_id_value1);        
      Task taskinfo= null;   


}                        
catch(Exception e)                        
{                        
      System.out.println("error occured" + e);                        
}]]>
    </bpelx:exec>
```

Will anyone please tell me do I need to refer jar file in terms of BPEL process also.

even same class I can use in my java files in the same project. (for other class its working like OfficerList)

Environment is : Oracle SOA 11g, Jdeveloper

please suggest something.

Comment: Any one have any idea please share. every time whil deployment I am facing incorrect class path error.

Comment: Check server logs for ClassNotFoundException or NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: problem resolved, it was related to classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting that the IMPORT statements does not work.  Most of the time I do import, but turn around and use the full package/class name for it.  Have you try using the full package/class as follow?

```
  com.ura.dams.workflow.process.OfficerList officerlist= 
                  new com.ura.dams.workflow.process.OfficerList();               
   ...

  oracle.bpel.services.workflow.task.model.Task taskinfo= null;
```